# Bootstrap 3 - Column doesn't fill entire grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a row with 3 columns each `col-sm-4`. As per a 12 column grid, this should fill up the entire width of the screen. For some reason a tiny portion on the edge is left out (please see image below). The same does not happen on any other columns on the site.

[image]

Here is code:

```
<!-- Social -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="social row">
        <div class="twitter col-sm-4">
            <p><i class="icon-twitter icon-3x"></i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="youtube col-sm-4">
            <p><i class="icon-youtube icon-3x"></i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="facebook col-sm-4">
            <p><i class="icon-facebook icon-3x"></i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
/*************** 
    social
***************/
.social p{
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.twitter {
    background-color: #3C92CF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
    z-index: 3;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.youtube {
    background-color: #B1243B;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
    z-index: 3;
    padding-bottom: 1%
}

.facebook {
    background-color: #39579A;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
    z-index: 3;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's not a margin/padding? Also, `container` typically puts margins on the left and right.

Comment: can you provide the link to your webpage

Comment: There is no left/right padding. And I forced the container to be `width:100%`

Comment: @kougiland it's still local. Should I provide any other part of the code?

Comment: then the jsfiddle please

Comment: Jsfiddle will be a great help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a rounding error. Your container width is not divisible by three, so there is two pixels left. Since CSS doesn't work on a subpixel level, I would suggest to mask it with the background color:

```css
.social {
    background-color: #39579A; /* same as the last column color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typically a margin on inner containers if I remember correctly -20px.